# How to plot all combinations of matrix column data without using GGally in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I have a species matrix with 4 species. I want to plot their abundances against one another in ggplot2 without using ggpairs. I'm not sure how best to convert it into a dataset that can be plotted with facet_wrap for every species pair except with itself (6 plots in total) with linear regression fit. I also don't know how I would then label the axes for each row since it's all different (Plot 1:: x = sp.1, y = sp.2; Plot2 x = sp.2, y = sp.3)

```
#Data-Set
sp1 <- rnorm(72, mean = 4, 1)
sp2 <- rnorm(72, mean = 2, 1)
sp3 <- rnorm(72, mean = 3, 1)
sp4 <- rnorm(72, mean = 9, 1)

sp.abd <- data.frame(sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach at reshaping the data and pairing the variables using tidyr::pivot_longer and dplyr::left_join.

```
library(tidyverse)
sp.abd %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  mutate(dummy = 1) -> sp.abd.long

sp.abd.long %>%
  left_join(sp.abd.long, by = "dummy") %>%
  filter(name.x != name.y) %>%
  ggplot(aes(value.x, value.y)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.1) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  facet_grid(name.x ~ name.y)
```

[image]

Alternatively, to just get the six main comparisons with no blank facets:

```
sp.abd.long %>%
  left_join(sp.abd.long, by = "dummy") %>%
  filter(name.x < name.y) %>%
  mutate(label = paste(name.x, "vs.", name.y)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(value.x, value.y)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.1) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~label)
```

[image]

Comment: No, I don't want a pairs and I don't want the empty cells either. I just need the six graphs all arranged two rows or something. That's why its tripping me up so much...

Comment: Not sure I understand yet. Perhaps add `mutate(label = paste(name.x, "vs.", name.y)) %>%` and then end with `facet_wrap(~label)`?